# Как сделать подгрузку данных в tableview, когда tableview достиг конца

Tags: ios, swift

Всем здравствуйте
У меня есть метод который выводит в `tableview` новости
`https://abctv.kz/ru/api/v1/getPopularNews`
Я хочу выводить 10 записей, а потом когда записи закончились, то доставать еще 10 записей и так далее
Как я реализовал вывод записей в `tableview`

```
 struct Welcome: Codable {
        let error: Int
        let data: [Datum]
    }

    struct Datum: Codable {
        let id: Int
        let title: String
        let link: String
        let teaser, delayDate: String
        let cat: Cat
        let image: String

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case id, title, link, teaser
            case delayDate = "delay_date"
            case cat, image
        }
    }

    struct Cat: Codable {
        let categoryID: Int
        let slug, description: String
        let published: Int
        let title, seoTitle, seoDescription, seoKeywords: String
        let ogTitle, ogDescription: String
        let id: Int

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case categoryID = "category_id"
            case slug, description, published, title
            case seoTitle = "seo_title"
            case seoDescription = "seo_description"
            case seoKeywords = "seo_keywords"
            case ogTitle = "og_title"
            case ogDescription = "og_description"
            case id
        }
    }

    var arrData = [Datum]()

    func getNews(){
        let jsonURL = "https://abctv.kz/\(api_lang)/api/v1/getPopularNews?limit=50"
        guard let url = URL(string: jsonURL) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [unowned self] (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let data_new = try decoder.decode(Welcome.self, from: data)

                let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])

                if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {

                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.arrData = data_new.data
                    self.tableview.reloadData()

                }



            } catch {
                print("Error is : \n\(error)")
            }
            }.resume()
    }

    func getNewData(){
        let jsonURL = "https://abctv.kz/\(api_lang)/api/v1/getPopularNews?limit=10?offset=2"
        guard let url = URL(string: jsonURL) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [unowned self] (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let data_new = try decoder.decode(Welcome.self, from: data)

                let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])

                if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {

                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.arrData = data_new.data
                    self.tableview.reloadData()

                }



            } catch {
                print("Error is : \n\(error)")
            }
            }.resume()
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.arrData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "inbusiness_cell") as! InBusinessTableViewCell
        let dn = arrData[indexPath.row]
        let strURL1:String = "https://abctv.kz\(dn.image)"

        let url = URL(string: "https://abctv.kz\(dn.image)")
        cell.new_image.kf.setImage(with: url)

        cell.new_text.text = dn.title

        cell.new_type.text = dn.cat.title

        return cell
    }
```

Как мне сделать это?

Answer (score 2):

Можете сделать это разными способами. Приведу пару примеров:

1. В конец добавлять пустую ячейку/ячейку с индикатором загрузки (как задизайните) и когда она становится видимой - догружать данные. После подгрузки эту ячейку снова же поместить в конец.
2. Отслеживать номер ячейки которая показывается и если это последняя текущая ячейка - подгружать новую порцию данных.
3. Отслеживать текущий scroll offset и если будет определено, что достигнут "низ", то подгружать новую порцию данных.

Comment: Не могли бы вы привести пример кода?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте методы протокола UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching. Пример кода можно посмотреть здесь:
https://andreygordeev.com/2017/02/20/uitableview-prefetching/